# Verify downloaded files from FTP

Tags: php, ftp

Just a quick question, is it possible to verify the files downloaded from FTP? I am currently using [`ftp_get()`](http://php.net/ftp_get) to get my files. The only way I can think of is using [`ftp_size()`](http://php.net/ftp_size) to compare the locally saved files.

Comment: You'd have to checksum the file on both the server and the client, and I'm not sure if all FTP servers support checksums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're verifying it against another file, then use sha1 hashes to compare.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php

If you just want to know if the download itself completed, rely on the return of the ftp_get method

```
if(!ftp_get($myfile)) return 'damn';
```

Comment: yub, i want to verify the files saved from ftp_get() against those in the ftp to ensure the files are saved properly before i remove them from the FTP.